# Angular material: Open overlay on the top

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having the simplest possible overlay. Its working fine but the problem is, it always opens at the bottom of the origin div. I want it to open at the top by default and auto-adjust if top is out of view port.
How do I achieve that?

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-demo-gqaerz?file=app/app.component.html)

Code to open overlay:

```
openSpaghettiPanel() {
    // TODO(jelbourn): separate overlay demo for connected positioning.
    let strategy = this.overlay.position()
        .connectedTo(
            this._overlayOrigin.elementRef,
            {originX: 'start', originY: 'bottom'},
            {overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'top'} );

    let config = new OverlayConfig({positionStrategy: strategy});
    let overlayRef = this.overlay.create(config);

    overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(SpagettiPanel, this.viewContainerRef));
  }
```

Comment: I can't provide a complete answer (specifically auto-adjusting if top is out of viewport). But `originY` as `top` and `overlayY` as `bottom` will put it on top of the button instead of the bottom. Does that help?

Comment: That part is working but I wish auto-adujist would work too.

Comment: Sorry I don't have the answer to the rest, I'm not familiar with Angular Material. Just wanted to throw that suggestion out there (and that's why I used a comment and not an answer).